# Highcharts - doughnut charts, gap when only one point in series

Tags: highcharts

At the top of doughnut charts with only 1 point in the series, there is always a tiny gap between the start and end of the slice:

http://jsfiddle.net/6E2Bx/

```
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: 'pink',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'See the gap at 0 degrees',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -30,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white',
                    textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                }
            },
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            center: ['50%', '50%']
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '70%',
        data: [
            ['Full', 1]
        ]

    }
```

Close up of the gap:

[image: gap]

Am I missing some setting here?

I would prefer not to modify the drawing/svg elements directly, I feel like `borderWidth: 0` should be handling this.

Comment: See [that](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1828) discussion. It's not decided which is the better approach. Feel free to add comment :)

Comment: Than you for the link! @PawełFus